# How to make more text with radio to drop down?

Tags: html, input, radio-button, html-table

My question is how do I make this code drop down after you click on the other code:

```
   <table><tr><td>
    <h3>What power does you character have?</h3>
    <label><input type="radio" name="prefer" value="1"  /> Speed</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="prefer" value="2"  /> Strength</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="prefer" value="3"  /> Invisablity</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="prefer" value="4"  /> Flight</label><br/>
</td></tr></table>
```

this is the code I want to drop down (if you clicked on Speed)

```
   <table><tr><td>
    <h3>Does he can slow down time?</h3>
    <label><input type="radio" name="prefer" value="1"  /> Speed</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="prefer" value="2"  /> Strength</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="prefer" value="3"  /> Invisablity</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="prefer" value="4"  /> Flight</label><br/>
</td></tr></table>
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Well... first you should stop using tables, because this data does not belong in a table at all. Those are lists, and should be put in `<ul>`. As for what you're asking, you'll need to have some javascript to show and hide items based on what the user selects.

Answer (score 0):

you can accomplish this using an accordion.

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion(   {collapsible: true, active: false });
  } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Does he can slow down time?</h3>
  <div>
    <label><input type="radio" name="prefer" value="1"  /> Speed</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="prefer" value="2"  /> Strength</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="prefer" value="3"  /> Invisablity</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="prefer" value="4"  /> Flight</label><br/>
  </div>    
</div>
```